# Mysql-connector-java jar creates No TLDs error

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I added a jar file mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar to my $CATALINA_HOME/lib/ folder so I could use this library for connection pooling for mysql.

I running a dedicated server with Centos 6.6 X64 with Cpanel.
I installed jdk8 in /opt/jdk1.8.0_25 and installed tomcat 8 by untarring the download in the /home/username/ folder. I followed this tutorial:
http://tecadmin.net/install-tomcat-8-on-centos-rhel-and-ubuntu/

A simple "Hello World" servlet is running by deploying a .war file in the public_html folder

However now when I start up Tomcat (8.0.15) in the catalina.out file I see the error:

```
09-Dec-2014 17:45:49.152 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
09-Dec-2014 17:45:49.182 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /home/username/public_html/J.war
09-Dec-2014 17:45:49.592 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
09-Dec-2014 17:46:04.623 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [14,997] milliseconds.
09-Dec-2014 17:46:04.657 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /home/username/public_html/J.war has finished in 15,474 ms
```

And the connection pooling doesn't work. At my previous server the hosting company had setup tomcat with Cpanel and this worked just fine. I did not change the servlets so that cannot be the problem either.

My environment variables are:

```
CATALINA_HOME=/home/username/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_25/jre
JAVA_PATH=/opt/jdk1.8.0_25/jre
PATH=/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr
/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_25/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
:/root/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_25/bin
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_25
CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/jdk/lib/classes.zip
```

The last CLASSPATH I do not understand because there is no file classes.zip on the server.

I also tried adding the jar file directly in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the deployed war file but this also did not work (the error in catalina.out was gone though).

Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong with adding the library?

Thanks

Comment: Have you compiled/build your project with connector jar file ?

Comment: I use a war file, which is compiled on the server which should use the jar files from the lib folder. On my pc I also just added the jar to the lib folder in tomcat and then the servlet works fine. This method also worked on my previous server (with the same servlet/war). One other point is that the TLD error is given with every servlet on the server it does not matter if the servlet is using the jar or not. So I think it has to do with some configurations in tomcat which I've done wrong.

Comment: Does nobody have a solution to this problem? @Miya How do I compile the project with the jar file?

Comment: Which IDE are you using to develop project? Is it working fine with your IDE?

Comment: @Miya Hi thanks for the help, I found the problem. That the connection pooling didn't work had nothing to do with the TLD message (this apparently is just a warning). In the context.xml file I made two errors 1) I wrote type="javax.sql.DataSource" with a small s. And I had to add factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory". The factory line I did not add on my previous server and it worked fine, what does this do? thanks